# Added Views appear at top of screen

Tags: android, xml

I've been trying to add multiple textviews and buttons when onClick, and this is the best code I have found that actually works:

```
    RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setText("Shift" + mShiftCount);

    EditText edittv = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    edittv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    relative.addView(tv);
    relative.addView(edittv);
```

This seems to be the best code to add additional items that are alike to that of what I already have in my main.XML file. 
My issue is that when these are added, they appear at the top of the screen and I am unsure how to add further parameters to the objects.
How would I go about placing the textview and edittext below my other elements specified in the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` (refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)) when you add the views like tv and edittv to the `RelativeLayout`. In your `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, you need to define the same parameters you would give to your other `RelativeLayout` objects. Here is an example:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.idOfWhatYouWantToBeBelowOf);
addView(tv, params);
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! I just have one other issue, how do I make the EditText appear below the TextView?
This doesn't work:

Comment: 'RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.syncCalendar);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv);'

Comment: You need to give you `tv` object an id by simply doing `tv.setId(123)` (or some random number). Then in the layout parameters just use 123 as the id number. Remember to accept this answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot, I thought I had wasted a whole night here but this has fixed my problems :).

Answer (score 0):

First off there are definitely some static components to your view and some dynamic components. can you please specify what is your layout file so that i can give you a much more detail in your application.

Comment: My main.xml has a LinearLayout, a ScrollView, A RelativeLayout inside of that, and then numerous TextViews, Buttons, EditTextxs and AutoCompleteTextViews.